# using subclass's static variable in superclass

Tags: c++, variables, static, subclass

```
class Class1 {
Class1() { Class2::counter++;}
}

class Class2: public Class1 {
public:
static int counter;
}
```

The above is an example of what I am trying to do. I am trying to use a static variable of a subclass in the superclass but that gives me a compiler error since Class1 is initialized first and when the compiler reaches the Class2::counter++; it has not initialized Class2 yet and therefore I get a "Class2 has not been declared" error. How can I fix this? Do I need to change my logic completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may put definition of constructor `Class1` after `Class2` definition:

```
class Class1 {
public:
    Class1();
};

class Class2: public Class1 {
public:
    static int counter;
};

int Class2::counter = 0;

Class1::Class1() { Class2::counter++;}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/B3gDSY)

Comment: I guess I'll go with this one since it requires the least of changes to my code

Answer (score 2):

From a OOP perspective a parent class is not able to access to a child field or property, it should the opposite way a child accessing to a parent field or property. I'm wondering whyeyou need to access tora child field from the parent? If you provide more details what you are trying to achieve the best solution will be provided by someone.

Answer (score 1):

You could just pass a reference to your counter to the base class:

```
class Class1 {
public:
    Class1(int& counter) { ++counter; }
};

class Class2: public Class1 {
public:
    static int counter;
    Class2() : Class1(counter) { }
};

int Class2::counter = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

A rule of thumb:  *base classes don't access child class members or methods*.

If the base class needs something from a child class, declare an abstract virtual function in the base class for the child to implement.

Or move the common data members or methods into the base class.

In your case:

```
class Base
{
  virtual void increment_counter(void) = 0;
  void my_method(void)
  {
    increment_counter();
  }
};

class Child : public Base
{
  int counter;
  void increment_counter(void)
  {
    ++counter;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply define the constructor of class Class1 after the definition of Class2.

```
class Class1 {
public:
Class1();
}

class Class2: public Class1 {
public:
static int counter;
}

Class1::Class1() { Class2::counter++;}
```

Do not forget to define the static data member of Class2.:)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get freaky with templates, this sounds a possible use for the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). For example:

```
template <typename T>
class CRTBase
{
    CRTBase() { T::counter++; }
};

class CRTDerived : public CRTBase<CRTDerived>
{
public:
    static int counter;
};

int CRTDerived::counter = 0;
```